# make a function with async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

so i have an array with string inside there, and what i want to do is replacing some word with another word, so i make something like this

```
  let secFilm = result.data.films
  for (let s = 0; s < secFilm.length; s++) {
    secFilm[s] = secFilm[s].replace(/http/g, "https");
  }
```

but i know, if this method isn't effective enough, because it's only applied to ***result.data.films*** ,while there are other data besides this data

how can i make async function that data can be used dynamically, so i don't have to make one by one method for other data. Thank You.

Comment: use `map` method.

Comment: You don't need an `async` function, just a regular function will do.

Comment: Create a function that takes the array as argument?

Comment: @ThomasRyan i don't know how to do that in my code above sir sry

Comment: @trincot yes, the argument will be an array

Comment: Using `map` will be like: `let secFilm = result.data.films.map(s => s.replace(/http/g, "https"))`

Comment: So why not start writing that function? If you have a specific problem with that, then maybe ask about that specific issue? Currently your question does not have any code with a function definition... Also, asking for `async` is proposing a solution to a problem you do not state. Why do you think it must be async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figured out how it's done, sry guys

this how i do it

```
let secFilm = result.data.films
let secPilot = result.data.pilots

  function secure(arr){
    for (let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
      arr[k] = arr[k].replace(/http/g, "https");
    }
  }

  secure(secFilm, secPilot)
```

so i don't have to make async function, thank you to @Thomas
i know it's not the best method, but i think it's better than before

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertHTTP(arr=[]) {
    arr.forEach((val, index, arr) => {
        arr[index] = val.replace(/http/g, "https");
    });
}
```

I guess you don't need an async function instead you can use the above function if u need to change object value everywhere otherwise you can use a map function which creates a new array of value containing https and the original array also will be retained with HTTP

map function

```
function convertHTTP(httpArr=[]) {
    return httpArr.map(val => val.replace(/http/g, "https"));
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong. thank you